Springboot doesn't create mapstruct bean
I have some mappers with the following code:
import org.mapstruct.Mapper;
import org.mapstruct.MappingConstants;

@Mapper(componentModel = MappingConstants.ComponentModel.SPRING)
public interface DiaryPageMapper {
    DiaryPageEntity to(DiaryPageDTO diaryPageDTO);

    DiaryPageDTO from(DiaryPageEntity diaryPageEntity);
}

and my controller and services call these mappers with @Autowired dependency injection annotation such as:
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class DiaryPageService {

    @Autowired
    DiaryPageRepository diaryPageRepository;

    @Autowired
    DiaryPageMapper diaryPageMapper;
}

this is my dependencies in build.gradle:
    implementation 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.6.0'
    implementation 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.6.2'

when building the application, the main test gives the following error:
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'library.booklet.mapper.DiaryPageMapper' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1880)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1406)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1353)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:785)
    ... 56 more


how can I solve this problem?
I tried cleaning the project and cleaning the cache and restarting it again, and I checked in the build folder to see if it created the bean, but it didn't generate the bean.
build image

You have to put annotationProcessor "org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:${mapstructVersion}" on your dependencies section on build.gradle.

@Matheus and another person answered. the problem with importing mapstruct-processor was this one:
annotationProcessor 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.6.2'

